# Recognize text and draw a rectangle over text on camera preview

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin, android-camera2, text-recognition

In Camera preview i want to detect text & draw a rectangle overlay on **Paragraph/complete text** similar to camScanner.

I have used opencv Library but in this i am able to detect object but not able to draw a border/rectangle over complete visible text. I have also used android-Camera2Basic.(https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic). 
[image: something like this].

Comment: With OpenCV, you can change the bitmap that is going to be displayed. The problem is that text detection may take a while and the total latency will be too much.

Comment: Can you show an example of what your trying to achieve? In your sample image, are you trying to put a box around your computer keyboard or around each inidivual letter on the keyboard?